VBA code used to build a diverse portfolio of DFS lineups to minimize risk
This code works great and does exactly what I want but it takes around 10 minutes for the code for find 150 lineups. I am hoping to get help and learn how to make it much faster.
The goal of this code is as follows:

Search for each playerid in the wsbuild.Range("C2:J5001")
The first time it is found add each playerid to the dictionary
Then cut the lineup to rw.Cut Destination:=wsLineups.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Once the lineup has been cut, count the number of times each playerid shows up in the range on wslineups. If a playerid quantity is the same as the For count = 2 To HowManyLineups + 1 loop then I don't want to use it because the goal is to get a diverse set of lineups and not use the same players too often. Cut the lineup back to its original position on wsbuild.
If the cut lineup had all original players then keep it and move on to the next C.
Once I have looped through all playerids then remove all playerids from the dictionary and start over until If IsEmpty(Check) = False Then Exit For the desired number of lineups has been met.

Here is the code:
Option Explicit

Sub MLB_Step_2()

'Turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Define Macros workbook
Dim wbMacros As Workbook
Set wbMacros = Workbooks("Classic_Slates_Custom_Sum.xlsm")

'Define Dictionary
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

'Define wsData
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

'Define wsBuild
Dim wsbuild As Worksheet
Set wsbuild = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Build")

'Define wsLineups
Dim wsLineups As Worksheet
Set wsLineups = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lineups")

'Define Lastrow
Dim Lastrow As Integer

'Define rngCheck
Dim Check As Range
Dim C As Range

'Search for each playerid in the lineups range
Dim count As Integer
For count = 2 To HowManyLineups + 1
    Set Check = wsLineups.Range("A" & (HowManyLineups / 2) + 1)
    For Each C In wsData.Range("Q2", wsData.Cells(Rows.count, "Q").End(xlUp))
        Dim v As Long
        v = C.Value
        If dict.exists(CStr(v)) Then
            C.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            Dim f As Range
            Set f = wsbuild.Range("C2:J5001").Find(v, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, searchorder:=xlByRows)
            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                Dim rngrow As Integer
                rngrow = f.row
                Dim rw As Range
                Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 10)
                Dim c2 As Range
                For Each c2 In rw.Cells
                    dict(CStr(c2)) = True
                Next c2
                Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 37)
                
                'Cut the found lineup and paste to wsLineups
                rw.Cut Destination:=wsLineups.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            
                Lastrow = wsLineups.Range("AN" & wsLineups.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            
                C.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                
                Dim cell As Range
                
                'If the quantity of each player is equal to the count loop then cut the lineups back to its original place on wsbulid
                For Each cell In wsLineups.Range("AN2", "AN" & Lastrow)
                    If cell.Value = count Then
                        Lastrow = wsLineups.Range("A" & wsLineups.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
                        wsLineups.Range("A" & Lastrow, "AK" & Lastrow).Cut wsbuild.Range("A" & rngrow)
                        If wsbuild.Range("A" & rngrow) <> "" Then Exit For
                        Else
                    End If
                Next cell
            Else
                C.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        
        End If
        Set Check = wsLineups.Range("A" & (HowManyLineups / 2) + 1)
        If IsEmpty(Check) = False Then Exit For
        
    Next C
    wsData.Range("Q:Q").Interior.Color = xlNone
    If IsEmpty(Check) = False Then Exit For
    dict.RemoveAll
Next count

'Autofit columns
wsLineups.Range("A:AJ").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub


Here is images of each tab for visual help understand the code.




If you provide a download link for the workbook, I'll look at it.  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual may help.   Ideally, you should do all the work in Arrays.  Iterating over cells, cutting them and formatting them isn't ideal.  I strategy to replace the formatting with Conditional Formatting would be better.

@TinMan What is the best/approved way to provide you a download link?

@TinMan https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au1-g32xnKtH2VB8dB7HJXy509i6?e=cdy9AT
Let me know if this works!

Worksheet.CodeName
Read: Excel VBA Tutorial: Unlock the Secrets of Worksheet Code Names
Using CodeNames for worksheets in VBA significantly enhances code reliability and readability. Since CodeName refers to the internal identifier of a worksheet, it remains constant even if the sheet's name changes or is moved by the user. This eliminates the risk of runtime errors due to accidental renaming or reordering of sheets. Additionally, referencing a worksheet by CodeName simplifies the code because it removes the need to repeatedly refer to the Workbook and Worksheet objects, making the code cleaner and easier to maintain. Ultimately, using CodeNames leads to more robust and user-proof macros.

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
These declarations can be removed across all the modules by changing the Worksheet CodeNames.  Once the codename for Sheet1 is changed  to wsData, wsData will always refer to the wsData in ThisWorkbook.


I have noticed references to other Macro Workbooks in other modules.  Here is a helper function that will return a reference to a Worksheet in an external Workbook by CodeName.
Function GetExternalWorkSheetByCodeName(Workbook As Workbook, CodeName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
   
    For Each Worksheet In Workbook.Worksheets
        If Worksheet.[_CodeName] = CodeName Then
            Set GetExternalWorkSheetByCodeName = Worksheet
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub Example()
    Dim wbMacros As Workbook
    Set wbMacros = Workbooks("Classic_Slates.xlsm")
    Dim wsClassicData As Worksheet
    Set wsClassicData = GetExternalWorkSheetByCodeName(wbMacros, "wsData ")
End Sub

Performance
MLB_Step_2() took 129.9375 seconds to run on my machine.  During that time it made 1017 cuts that had to be cut back to their original positions.  TestCuts() took 74.3447265625 seconds to perform 1017 cuts.  Roughly 57% of the runtime could be saved by reworking the logic, so that, the Player ID counts are checked against the Exposures before any cuts are made.
Sub TestCuts()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To 1017
        Range("A2").Resize(1, 37).Cut Range("AA2")
        Range("AA2").Resize(1, 37).Cut Range("A2")
    Next
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub

Performing the counts using a Scripting.Dictionary and changing the logic to check the Player Id keys to be added to the lineup is at least one less the current count increment before cutting the cells would greatly improve the run time.  In this way, you could Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual which would be even more efficient.
Here are some functions I wrote that should help in refactoring the code.  The Keys would be the Player IDs from rw e.g. Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 10): Keys = rw.Value)
Function GetDFSDictionary(ws As Worksheet) As Object
    Dim Dict As Object
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Data As Variant
    With ws
        Data = .Range("AN2", Cells(Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Key As String
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Key = Data(r, 1)
        If Not Dict.Exists(Key) Then Dict.Add Key, Data(r, 2)
    Next
    
    Set GetDFSDictionary = Dict
End Function

Function FSDictionaryValidateCount(Dict As Object, Count As Long, Keys As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Key As String
    For r = 1 To UBound(Keys)
        Key = Keys(r, 1)
        If Dict.Exists(Key) Then 
            Rem - 1 is used because we want to do the checks before we Cut the cells. 
            If Dict(Key) > Count - 1 Then Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    FSDictionaryValidateCount = True
End Function

Function FSDictionaryIncrementKeyValues(Dict As Object, Keys As Variant)
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Key As String
    For r = 1 To UBound(Keys)
        Key = Keys(r, 1)
        If Dict.Exists(Key) Then
            Dict(Key) = 1
        Else
            Debug.Print Key; " not found"
        End If
    Next
End Function

Ideally
You should do all the work in memory using Arrays and Dictionaries and write the data back once to update the Build and once to update the Line Up.  This would probably be at least 30-50 times faster than the current code.
Refactored Code
KeyCounter Class
Option Explicit
Public Dictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary

Public Sub IncrementKeys(ByRef Keys As Variant)
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In Keys
        If Dictionary.Exists(CStr(Key)) Then
            Dictionary(CStr(Key)) = Dictionary(CStr(Key)) + 1
        Else
            Dictionary(CStr(Key)) = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
    
Public Sub DecrementKeys(ByRef Keys As Variant)
    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In Keys
        Dictionary(CStr(Key)) = Dictionary(CStr(Key)) - 1
    Next
End Sub
    
Function MaxKeyCount()
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim Max As Long
    
    For Each Key In Dictionary
        If Dictionary(CStr(Key)) > Max Then
            Max = Dictionary(CStr(Key))
        End If
    Next
    MaxKeyCount = Max
End Function

BuildData
Option Explicit
Public Data As Variant
Public BuildDataRanage As Range
Public Cursor As Long
Private Const FirstKeyColumn As Long = 3
Private Const LastKeyColumn As Long = 10
Private Const LastDataColumn As Long = 37

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Build")
        Set BuildDataRanage = .Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, LastDataColumn)
    End With
    Data = BuildDataRanage.value
End Sub

Function GotoKey(Key As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim LineUp(1 To LastKeyColumn) As Variant
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For c = 1 To LastKeyColumn
            If Data(r, c) = Key Then
                Cursor = r
                GotoKey = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function

Function GetCurrentKeys()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim LineUp(FirstKeyColumn To LastKeyColumn) As Variant

    For c = FirstKeyColumn To LastKeyColumn
        LineUp(c) = Data(Cursor, c)
    Next
    
    GetCurrentKeys = LineUp
End Function

Function GetRow(Optional EraseRow As Boolean = True) As Variant
    Dim c As Long
    Dim LineUp(1 To LastDataColumn) As Variant

    For c = 1 To LastDataColumn
        LineUp(c) = Data(Cursor, c)
        If EraseRow Then Data(Cursor, c) = ""
    Next

    GetRow = LineUp
End Function

Function UpdateBuild()
    BuildDataRanage = Data
End Function

Refactored MLB_Step_2
Place this in a standard module.
Option Explicit

Sub MLB_Step_2A(CountOfLineUps As Long)
    Const NumberOfKeys As Long = 10
    Const LastDataColumn As Long = 37
    Dim Lineups As Variant
    ReDim Lineups(1 To CountOfLineUps, 1 To LastDataColumn)
    
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    'Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Define wsLineups
    Dim wsLineups As Worksheet
    Set wsLineups = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lineups")

    Dim Keys As Variant, Key As Variant
    With wsLineups
        Keys = .Range("AM2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "AM").End(xlUp)).value
        .UsedRange.Columns("A:AL").Offset(1).ClearContents
    End With
    
    Dim DataClass As New BuildData
    Dim Counter As New KeyCounter
    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim NewKeys  As Variant
    Dim LineUp  As Variant
    Dim Pass As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Pass = 1
    Dim Its As Long
    
    Do
        Pass = Pass + 1
        For Each Key In Keys
            If Not Dict.Exists(CStr(Key)) Then
                If DataClass.GotoKey(Key) Then
                    NewKeys = DataClass.GetCurrentKeys()
                    Dim Key2 As Variant
                    For Each Key2 In NewKeys
                        Dict(CStr(Key2)) = True
                    Next
                        
                    Counter.IncrementKeys NewKeys
                    If Counter.MaxKeyCount = Pass Then
                        Counter.DecrementKeys NewKeys
                    ElseIf Counter.MaxKeyCount > Pass Then
                        Stop
                    Else
                        Count = Count + 1
                        LineUp = DataClass.GetRow(True)
                        For c = 1 To LastDataColumn
                            Lineups(Count, c) = LineUp(c)
                        Next
                        If Count = CountOfLineUps Then Exit Do
                    End If
                Else
                    Debug.Print Key; " not found"
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
        Dict.RemoveAll
    Loop While Pass < 500 'This is a safeguard and should never trigger
    
    wsLineups.Range("A:AJ").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    With wsLineups
        .Range("A2").Resize(CountOfLineUps, LastDataColumn).value = Lineups
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
    DataClass.UpdateBuild
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub

Usage
Pass in the actual number of expected Line Ups

MLB_Step_2A 75

Performance
MLB_Step_2: 117.1591796875 seconds
MLB_Step_2A 75: 0.5625 seconds
MLB_Step_2A was 208 times faster than the original code.
Notes
I added a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime for early Dictionary binding and so that I can take advantage of Intellisense.

"Here are some functions I wrote that should help in refactoring the code. The Keys would be the Player IDs from rw e.g. Set rw = f.EntireRow.Columns("A").Resize(1, 10): Keys = rw.Value)" Where would I define this? I have not wrapped my head around arrays yet. This is very helpful, thank you.

@safo2238 Using arrays, I got the runtime to ~1 sec down from ~111 secs but I'm having the damndest time getting the results to match, as expected.   I'll look at it again tomorrow.

Please let me know how I can help, and I appreciate the persistence.

@safo2238 It was a simple fix.  I didn't realize that the Exposure count skipped the first 2 columns.  The results now match.  Let me know if you need help implementing my refactored code.

Where do I put the BuildData and KeyCounter Class? I have been trying to implement this morning and struggling.

From the VBEditor insert menu add two classes and rename them BuildData and KeyCounter.

Public Dictionary As New Scripting.Dictionary I am getting an error "User-defined type not defined"

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
